# reactjs - show dialog on all pages using a button component, wherever it is included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my `react` app, I have a header with a show dialog button.
This header component is included in all pages as necessary.

My current logic to show the dialog is as follows:

- When user clicks the button, I dispatch an action to `redux` store `{ type:SHOW_DIALOG }`, and let the parent component handle the state change and draw the dialog.  I am using `material-UI` swipeable drawer component.

Handle Click event in an iconbutton in **header** component...

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    /*
     * temporary bypass surgery to avoid going through login dialog
     * dispatch({type:'SHOW_CONTACT_INFO'})
     * return;
     */
    if (!isLoggedIn)  dispatch({type: 'SHOW_LOGIN_DLG'})
    else router.push('/my-account')
  }
```

In the **parent** page, where the header is contained...

```
// ...other code
   <Container>
    {/* Whether or not to show the login dialog . */}
    {loginProcessState>=1 && loginProcessState<=7
       ?<LoginDialog type={loginProcessState===1?"login":"otp"} />
       : null}
    {/* if contact edit dialog is set to show, show it. */}
    {contactEditDisplay? <ProfileEditDialog />:null}
   </Container>
  );
```

But, since I have many pages (around 10 pages and server side rendering with NextJS), I will have to repeat the state management in all those pages where the dialog must be shown.

Excuse my lack of knowledge here.  Is it possible to avoid this dialog state check in the parent component / page.  If so, how can i do it?

Comment: Your goal is to display the `LoginDialog` across all pages, if certain checks are correct... is that right? Have you thought of rendering that `LoginDialog` with the root `<App/>` component? And then using `React.useContext` you can get to call that `dispatch` in various components to trigger `loginProcessState`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am triggering dispatch from the header component on click.  But the pages which include have to know that they have to check for the login_show state and then show (or not show) the dialog.  Isn't it?

Comment: Or do you mean to say, I should do that check in _app.js?  That looks like a good idea.  I am trying it out...

Comment: Alright, let me know how it goes.

Comment: It works.  I no longer have to put state management in each page !!!

Comment: Please promote your suggestion to answer, so I can upvote and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

- Move the `LoginDialog` component up and render it directly within the root `<App/>` component.
- And then use `React.useContext` to call that `dispatch` in various components to trigger `loginProcessState`.

The above should help you render the Login acros all components.